# Do I use 'do' or 'does' in this sentence: 'How do the imagery and/or metaphors used evoke suggestion?'

Tags: verbs, grammatical-number

I'm not sure which verb to use in this sentence - do or does? Your thoughts appreciated! I think the  problem is that the verb refers to a singular and plural noun.

Answer (score 1):

### How does the imagery

and

### How do the metaphors

Combined, you can use either as long as you use the correct one first.

> How does the imagery and/or metaphors used evoke suggestion?
>
> How do the metaphors and/or imagery used evoke suggestion?

Since you have two subjects, then `evoke` will always be in the 3rd person form.